# having trouble transforming a for loop of numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, numbers

This is what I have, but I'm trying to adjust it to create the image below

```
n=11    
for j in range(10):  
    n=n-1               
    for i in range(n): 

        print(i,end=" ")  
    print()
```

Image:

```
10

11 12

13 14 15

16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24

25 26 27 28 29 30

31 32 33 34 35 36 37

38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. :)

```
n=10
for j in range(10):
    i=0
    for i in range(j):
        print n,
        n = n+1
    print ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k=10
for i in range(1,10):
    a=0
    for j in range(k,55):
        a=a+1
        print j,

        if a==i:
            k=j+1
            break
    print
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
start = 10
stop = 54
n = 0

while True:
    numbers = range(start,start+n+1)
    for num in numbers:
        print(num, end=' ')
    print()
    print()
    n += 1
    start += n
    if start+n > stop:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> n=10
 >>> s=""
 >>> for i in range(1,10):
       for j in range(i):
         s=s+" "+str(n)
         n=n+1
       print s
       print "\n"
       s=""
```

Answer (score 0):

try this this will works

```
int main()
{


int i,k,number=10;
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
{

for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
{
cout<<" "<<number;

number++;
}
cout<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```